# Android Studio: Method call expected (Java)

Tags: android, android-studio, app-store

I'm new to Android Studio and am having trouble with this code; I'm getting an error which is informing me that a method call (TabbedActivity(intent)) was expected but I'm unsure what to do as I've never been faced with this before.

The program is supposed to open google when a button is pressed.

Thanks, and here's my code:

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

        final ImageButton button = findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://google.com");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                TabbedActivity(intent); ***<--- error!***
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Change the line to `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Thank you very much. Very much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://google.com");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent); ***<--- error!***
        }
```